# Make default sorting in "Purchase Order History" tab of ME23N?

Tags: sap

It seems I can only select and display it manually each time, with no apparent option of **saving** the current view. I want the "Purchase Order History" tab to automatically sort by GR/IR view as I open the transaction.

Screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki4Om.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It is done by regular [layout variants](https://help.sap.com/doc/a7b666550852bd7de10000000a44538d/3.6/en-US/865ec353b677b44ce10000000a174cb4.html) that exists in every standard table:

[image]

Just press *Save layout* and then do not forget to tick it as default

[image]

If you lack this button, then you simply do not have permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. What I'm trying to do is to default the view as it appears when clicking the "Change Display" button (the second one from the right in your screenshot) > GR/IR. Saving the layout doesn't seem to also save the current display.

Comment: what button do you mean? give a screenshot of that view

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/ssXJCEX

Comment: I've got your point. I cannot confirm this, but for 99% I'm sure that this is not customizable. You only can adjust the layouts of the existing views, not to set up the default view. However, if somebody more knowledgeable come he can always improve my answer

Comment: also, add your screenshot to the question body so that people can go in the right direction, otherwise you will never get the right answer

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully there's a solution to this! I added the screenshot to my question.